# What is the internal behaviour of exception handling?

Tags: java, exception

If there is exception, then an exception object is created.

If the exception was not handled, what happen to that exception object and what is the internal mechanism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [How uncaught exceptions are handled](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_uncaught_handler.shtml):

> Java actually handles uncaught exceptions according to the thread in
>   which they occur. When an uncaught exception occurs in a particular
>   thread, Java looks for what is called an uncaught exception handler,
>   actually an implementaiton of the interface UncaughtExceptionHandler.
>   The latter interface has a method handleException(), which the
>   implementer overrides to take appropriate action, such as printing the
>   stack trace to the console. As we'll see in a moment, we can actually
>   install our own instance of UncaughtExceptionHandler to handle
>   uncaught exceptions of a particular thread, or even for the whole
>   system.
>
> The specific procedure is as follows. When an uncaught exception
>   occurs, the JVM does the following:
>
> - it calls a special private method, dispatchUncaughtException(), on    the Thread class in which the exception occurs;
> - it then terminates the thread in which the exception occurred1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Exception object exist AND IS THROWN, then Rahul has already answered nicely.

Interesting what to do with new Exception object, not throwed. It's a programming technique to get some runtime info, like stack, place of call Exception constructor, etc.

```
            e= new Exception();
            StackTraceElement[] st = e.getStackTrace();
            for(StackTraceElement s:st)
            {
                s.getLineNumber()
            }
// NO throw
```